# Missing Id_Token Spring Oauth2 Auth Server and mod_auth_openidc

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, mod-auth-openidc

I'm trying to get a Spring security authorization server to work for resources secured behind Apache2 running mod_open_idc. When I access my resource it redirects me to the login page, but after I login I get redirected to a page that says Error in handling response type. If I look in the apache error log it says `oidc_proto_validate_code_response: requested flow is "code" but no "id_token" parameter found in the code response`. The url is returned with `/redirect_uri?code=f0I4GB&state=DdA1Udo1lllEeed3V8LppkOtxPg` at the end. Here are the relevant parts of my apache configuration

```
OIDCProviderIssuer https://URL:9999/uaa/oauth
OIDCProviderAuthorizationEndpoint https://URL:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
OIDCProviderJwksUri https://URL:9999/uaa/oauth/token_key
OIDCProviderTokenEndpoint https://URL:9999/uaa/oauth/token
OIDCProviderUserInfoEndpoint https://URL:9999/uaa/user
OIDCScope "openid"

OIDCClientID revproxy
OIDCClientSecret revsecret
OIDCSSLValidateServer Off
OIDCCryptoPassphrase MyPassword
OIDCRedirectURI https://URL/home/redirect_uri

<Location "/home">
     AuthType openid-connect
     Require valid-user
     ProxyPass  https://URL:8443/
     ProxyPassReverse  https://URL:8443/
  </Location>
```

I'm happy to post any spring code as well, I just don't know what parts might be at issue. I also have no idea which piece I have configured incorrectly, my gut says mod_auth_openidc, but it could be spring.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Spring is not configured for OpenID Connect but rather for OAuth 2.0 only. For OpenID Connect clients using the scope `openid`, the Provider is supposed to return an `id_token`. Apparently Spring is misconfigured or perhaps does not even support OpenID Connect.

Comment: is there a way to this, using any custom code or implementation? in particular for the implicit grant flows? by introducing the id_token in the redirected url, if there was a scope of openid in the request?